# Job Tracker web interface

Tags: hadoop

I followed the tutorialshttp://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html and installed hadoop 2.4.1 as pseudo distributed cluster. I created a ubuntu VM using OracleVM and installed hadoop as mentioned in the link. It was setup fine and able to run the examples. However the job tracker URL is not working. :50030 gives page not found. I also tried netstat on the server and there is no process waiting on 50030 port . Do i need to start any other service ? What are the possible reasons  ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute this:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

Or JobTracker won't start.

(In my case, `$HADOOP_HOME` is in `/usr/local/hadoop`)

Comment: Not sure if it's a setting, but this ended up listening on port 19888.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `mapred.job.tracker.http.address` in mapred-site.xml
If the port is different, use that.

Also check if jobtracker is running. Check the jobtracker logs.

Comment: How to check if jobtracker is running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the following command

http://localhost:50030/

Job Tracker web UI.